# Crash in Xcode Playground

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground, apple-radar

In Xcode 12.0 (12A7209) Playground I receive a crash when use this code:

```
struct Pippo: Codable {
    var primo: String
    var secondo: String
    var terzo: String
    var quarto: String
    var quinto: String
    var sesto: String
    var settimo: String
    var ottavo: String
    var nono: String
}

let pippo = Pippo(primo: "1",
                  secondo: "1",
                  terzo: "1",
                  quarto: "1",
                  quinto: "1",
                  sesto: "1",
                  settimo: "1",
                  ottavo: "1",
                  nono: "1")

print(pippo)
```

The crash code messagings is:
Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18).
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.

Note that if I remove some var from struct everything work well

```
struct Pippo: Codable {
    var primo: String
    var secondo: String
//    var terzo: String
//    var quarto: String
//    var quinto: String
//    var sesto: String
    var settimo: String
    var ottavo: String
    var nono: String
}

let pippo = Pippo(primo: "1",
                  secondo: "1",
//                  terzo: "1",
//                  quarto: "1",
//                  quinto: "1",
//                  sesto: "1",
                  settimo: "1",
                  ottavo: "1",
                  nono: "1")

print(pippo)
```

I think it is a bug in Xcode.
Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: No issue on my side. Tested with Xcode 12.0.1.

Comment: Are you sure? I tried the code in two different Mac, both with Xcode 12.0.1, and in both Mac I found the playground error.